# What is the best way to randomly select an image from a website in HTML?

Tags: html

I am building myself a home page for my browser and I thought of the idea of having a different background every day based on the top posts of a subreddit.

I am currently using this code for the background

```
        body {
          background-image: url(bg.jpg);
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-attachment: fixed;
          background-size: cover;
        }
        </style>
```

I wanted to select a random image from "top for today" part of earth porn [found here](https://www.reddit.com/r/EarthPorn/top/). Would you guys know any API's out there or anything code that I could use to randomly select from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t do this in HTML alone. However if you use php you could accomplish it like so:

```
<?php
$bg_urls = [
“URL_TO_FIRST_IMAGE”,
“URL_TO_SECOND_IMAGE”
];

$random_index = array_rand($bg_urls);
$random_url = $bg_urls[ $random_index ];
?>

<body style=“background-image: url(<?php echo $random_url ?>)”>
```

You could also accomplish it with JavaScript by doing similar logic to grab a random element from an array of urls and then targeting the body element on the page and dynamically changing the style.

Best of luck!